# Minecraft runs slow, but high fps

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I play Minecraft, it runs choppy. I usually get around 200 fps but for some reason it still looks slow. Then sometimes out of nowhere it runs really really smooth.

My system specifications.

CPU: Intel Core i5 4460 (4 cores)
GPU: Sapphire AMD R9 290 (4GB)
RAM: 8GB 
PSU: Corsair CX600

At the moment I am using Linux Mint, but I still had this problem in 
Windows 8.1

Comment: Is it vanilla Minecraft?  If not, have you tried running vanilla, and seeing how it works?

Comment: It's vanilla Minecraft.

Comment: what video configs do you have?

Comment: When you say it "looks slow" do you mean that normally you have 200 fps in-game but occasionally drop to something lower? or that the in-game fps counter stays constant but if still appears to drop frames? Have you checked your video settings for vSync/max FPS settings? (screenshots pls?)

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure VSync is turned off in settings. Also, make sure your max FPS in Unlimited, or at least high enough. Or try to make your render distance shorter. If that doesn't help, you can always install [Optifine](https://optifine.net/downloads).

Comment: On my client VSync makes my game run at ~30 FPS, then I turn it off and drop to ~7 FPS.  Yeah, Yeah, My PC is a Dinosaur...